# How to determine what 即 means in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I was reading an advertisement that says:  '阿里云免费体验! 注册即获得高达300美元体验套餐! 立即开通阿里云全球服务!'

Would 即获得 mean 'immediately obtain?' 即 can mean so many different things, it's a bit confusing.

Many thanks,
Rachel

Comment: see dictionaries: then, as soon as, "with registration you obtain ..."

Answer (score 1):

[Dictionary](http://www.zdic.net/z/16/js/5373.htm) gives 6 meanings:

> 1. 就是：知识～力量。
> 2. 当时或当地：～日。～刻。～席。～景。在～。～兴（xìng ）。
> 3. 就，便：黎明～起。
> 4. 假如，倘若：～使。～便（biàn ）。～或。～令。
> 5. 靠近：不～不离。
> 6. 到，开始从事：～位。

With translations and comments, comments in italics:

> 1. is:
>
>    - 知识即力量 = Knowledge is power.
>    - *This usage of 即 is more formal and less often heard colloquially.*
> 2. this (time or place):
>
>    - 即日 = today;
>    - 即刻 = right now;
>    - 即席 = with improvisation (lit. [in] this seat);
>    - 即景 = the immediate (poetic) environment;
>    - 在即 = soon;
>    - 即兴 = with improvisation (lit. [by] that [time's] mood)
> 3. then:
>
>    - 黎明即起 = [as soon as] dawn [comes], then [you should] get up
>    - *the example cited is actually Classical Chinese, so you would not hear this colloquially*
> 4. if:
>
>    - 即使 = even if
>    - 即便 = even if
>    - 即或 = even if
>    - 即令 = even if
>    - *I don't even know the last two.*
> 5. come near:
>
>    - 不即不离 = keep at a respectful distance (lit. neither approach nor leave)
>    - *The example cited is a Buddhist term, and I have never heard of it.*
> 6. to start working at some position:
>
>    - 即位 = to start working at some position
>    - *即位 is idiomatic, I would say.*

Finally, a list of the words that you would hear colloquially:

- 即日 = today;
- 即刻 = right now;
- 即席 = with improvisation (lit. [in] this seat);
- 即景 = the immediate (poetic) environment;
- 在即 = soon;
- 即兴 = with improvisation (lit. [by] that [time's] mood)
- 即使 = even if
- 即便 = even if
- 即位 = to start working at some position

(From meanings 2,4,6)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, 即获得 is "immediately obtain", The definition of 即 is by context, it is "immediately" or "right now" here.

Answer (score 0):

即 here means immediately. If you register AliCloud you will then obtain the service set.

As I can think of, 即 can be used in several ways:

- that is ..., is just ..., similar to 就是, e.g. 知识即力量
- to start working at some position, e.g. 即位
- immediately, as in your sentence
- to make assumptions, similar to even if..., e.g. 即使

There could be more than what are listed above.
Hope it helps.